# Unknown / empty background task after calling BackgroundDownloadAsync or BackgroundUploadAsync from Live SDK

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, onedrive, live-sdk

Any idea why there will be an "empty" task listed under Lifecycle Events whenever a call to BackgrouDownloadAsync or BackgroundUploadAsync is made?

I can't post a picture yet. Please refer to the originally post in http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/39944e7d-feb2-4e06-b980-6ff41588ec50/unknown-empty-background-task?forum=wpdevelop

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I did to replace BackgroundDownloadAsync and BackgroundUploadAsync, omitting any try-catch and error checking codes. These calls will not cause the empty entry in "Lifecycle Events" drop-down. Not sure if it is due to issue in VS 2013.

To download (this is messy, there must be another way)

```
LiveConnectClient connectClient = new LiveConnectClient(this.Session);
LiveOperationResult _opResult = await connectClient.GetAsync(FileID + "/content");
dynamic _result = _opResult.Result;

CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, new Uri(_result.location as string, UriKind.Absolute));
HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.SendRequestAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead).AsTask(cts.Token);

using (var _stream = (await OutputFile.OpenStreamForWriteAsync()).AsOutputStream())
{
    await response.Content.WriteToStreamAsync(_stream).AsTask(cts.Token);
    await _stream.FlushAsync();
}
```

To upload

```
LiveConnectClient connectClient = new LiveConnectClient(this.Session);
using (Stream stream = await InputFile.OpenStreamForReadAsync())
{
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        LiveOperationResult _opResult = await connectClient.PutAsync(Awesome2FolderID + "/files/" + OneDriveFilename, reader.ReadToEnd());
    }
}
```